# UIView.translatesAutoResizing is false in viewDidLoad(), true in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Tags: uiview, ios-autolayout, autoresizingmask

I have a plain old `UIView`, created in IB, so its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag should be set to **false**. And sure enough, it *is* — in `viewDidLoad()`. But by the time `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` rolls around, the value has morphed to **true**. And of course the constraint generated by the translation conflicts with one of my own constraints.

How or where is this flag being changed?

The upshot is I get the beloved "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" console output. But changing the flag back to **false** in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` fixes the conflict. So I know *what* to do, but I don't see *why*. (Yes I have cleaned the project and restarted Xcode.)

Comment: FWIW, inspecting the Storyboard's XML, *all* views have the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag set to `"NO"`. The project *did* start out with no Auto Layout, which was added later. Somehow the flag is "sticky".

Answer (score 0):

Apple docs make clear that when the Storyboard is set to use Auto Layout, and one of its Views has no constraints, iOS contrives to *give it* some constraints. The surprise is the chosen mechanism: the OS automagically sets the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag to **true** right before layout.

It's an approach I might have used too: by flicking one switch, the OS assures that the auto-generation of constraints takes the same code path for IB-created Views as for programmatically-created Views. (Which have the flag set to **true** by default.)

In my case, I *was* clearing the pre-existing constraints in code before programmatically creating new ones. But I guess the magic re-setting of the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag happened in between those two actions.